# How can I make the following .keypress event handler work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run the following event handler listed below; it was originally a keydown function, but I need to configure the keypress instead. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(event) { 
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            if (event.which === 37) {
                currentPosition = (currentPosition>0) ?    parseInt(currentPosition)-1 : maxFocusablePosition;  
                console.log(' shift + left');

                focusPosition(currentPosition);  
                } 

            else if (event.which === 39) {
                currentPosition = (currentPosition<maxFocusablePosition) ? parseInt(currentPosition)+1 : 0; 
                console.log('shift + right');

                focusPosition(currentPosition);  
                }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**The `keypress` event is triggered when a printable character is generated.** Since your code is looking for the Shift key and an Arrow key (both keys that do not produce a printable character), you won't hit any of the branches of your `if` statement.

You need to use `keyup` or `keydown`.

Comment: Interesting. There is no way to use keypress for these non-printable characters?

Comment: Non-printable characters do not generate that event. You could use a `keydown` event handler to trap for them and then trigger the `keypress` event manually if they were pressed (not sure why you'd want this though), but `keypress` is about the character produced, not the actual key that was hit - - that's what `keyup` and `keydown` are for.